# select top n from dbo.XXXXX where tradetype in ('a', 'b', 'c')

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, distinct

I have a bit of a problem creating a query to assemble the `SELECT` queries below into one query, instead of running each one manually.  This helps myself to one create CSV file easier and quicker

```
select top 200 * from dbo.abacus where  type =  'A'
select top 200 * from dbo.abacus where  type =  'B'
select top 200 * from dbo.abacus  where type =  'E'
select top 200 * from dbo.abacus  where type =  'F'
select top 200 * from dbo.abacus  where type =  'F'
select top 200 * from dbo.abacus  where type =  'FX'
select top 200 * from dbo.abacus  where type =  'E'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `UNION` :

```
select top 200 * from dbo.abacus where  type =  'A'
union
select top 200 * from dbo.abacus where  type =  'B'
union
select top 200 * from dbo.abacus  where type =  'E'
union
select top 200 * from dbo.abacus  where type =  'F'
union
select top 200 * from dbo.abacus  where type =  'F'
union
select top 200 * from dbo.abacus  where type =  'FX'
union
select top 200 * from dbo.abacus  where type =  'E'
```

Comment: Cheers, Is there anyway for this to be done using just one query rather that union for all selects

Comment: Not really. If you try for example
"select top 200 * from dbo.abacus where  type in ('A', 'B'...)", or even TOP 1400, nothing guarantees that you will get 200 of each.

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 200 * from dbo.abacus where type = 'a'
union 
select top 200 * from dbo.abacus where type = 'b'
```

More reading from here  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026(v=sql.100).aspx